# Which TeX/LaTeX delimiters can I use in Moodle?

Tags: latex, moodle

I am trying to integrate TeX/LaTeX into my posts on [Moodle](https://moodle.org/), but I am not sure which delimiters I can use. Which delimiters am I allowed to use?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Moodle documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Using_TeX_Notation):

> To invoke the TeX filter, use the $$ symbols to open and close statements.

However, earlier in the documentation, it is written:

> If you use the Moodle native TeX Notation, you have to realize that this is not the only way of using TeX in Moodle and there are quite a few other "flavors" in the Tex world. You must also accept that the Moodle implementation of TeX is very limited, and a lot of things that work in other varieties of TeX and Latex will not work in TeX Notation. For example, there are three major [Tex modes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/tex/course/intro2.html), but the Moodle core Tex filter employs only one. To make matters even more confusing, Moodle Docs now use [Tex Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html), which uses the delimiters `<math> statement </math>` to denote TeX statements, yet these pages demonstrate the use of tokens, the $$ statement $$ token, that implement TeX in Moodle's native TeX Notation. Essentially, what may work in one Tex implementation, may not work in another - yet a lot of the actual maths coding is exactly the same, no matter how it is denoted.

which suggests that other delimiters can be used. In my experience, I was able to use the LaTeX delimiters `\(`,`\)`,`\[`, and `\]`. The advantage of these delimiters over the `$$` delimiter that is mentioned in the documentation is that I can switch between in-line mode and display mode. Moreover, the `$$` delimiter only allows display mode.

To test out these delimiters, you can use the [Moodle sandbox](https://sandbox.moodledemo.net/) to make some posts.